# How to use savedInstanceState Bundle in onLoadFinished?

Tags: android, android-loader

I have a question about Loaders. In my activity, I have a list of items and support multiple selection with the ActionMode class. When the user rotates the device, I don't want the user to loose her selection, that's why in oSaveInstanceState I save the info whether the multiselection mode is on, and which indices are selected. In onCreate, after I load the list of items, I check if the bundle state is not null, and if so, I proceed to reapply the selections and restart the ActionMode. All of this is pretty easy and works fine when loading happens on the main thread, as I can serially load the items and optionally reapply the selections.

Now I would like to perform loading in the background using a subclass of AsyncTaskLoader. The idea is:

- create and trigger loading in onCreate():

  ```
  // forceLoad() seems necessary, otherwise Loader.startLoading is never called
  getLoaderManager().initLoader(id, null, this).forceLoad();
  ```
- in LoaderCallbacks.onCreateLoader, a subclass of AsyncTaskLoader is created
- in Loader.loadInBackground() I perform the loading logic and return a List of items
- in LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished() I receive the Loader and the List loaded by it, create a custom RecyclerView.Adapter and set it on the RecyclerView

All of this works fine, but I don't know how to apply the selections after rotation. For that, I need the savedInstanceState bundle in the LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished() method.

I do have an idea: use the savedInstanceState Bundle as the 2nd argument to the initLoader() method in onCreate(). I don't know whether I am supposed to do so, though - is the Bundle mine, or can the system cleanup/recycle it after onCreate/onRestoreInstanceState? The loader would not be a Loader<List> but a Loader<Something>, and Something keeps my loaded List and the Bundle - this way the bundle would be passed around until the very place where it's needed - after the adapter is set on the RecyclerView - to perform the selections and start the ActionMode.

All of this seems a lot of work and inelegant, but definitely doable. How would you go about it? Is there any canon way?

Comment: Just store the saved state in a local variable, and use it upon receiving the result set when the `Loader` is finished loading. Your proposed solution will not work, as `initLoader()` reuses loaders that have already been initialized with that id, so the `Bundle` would not get delivered at all.

Comment: You are right, thanks. Where should I store it as a local variable? Or do you mean a member field in whatever implements the LoaderCallbacks? In my case, it is the Activity.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Note that in case `onSaveInstanceState()` is called again before the result set is delivered, you will also have to resave the state from that variable.